# Login Using Phone number firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to login a existing user by getting his phone number. I dont want to sent vertification at time of login because it is already send at time of sign Up

I want signup user with 
Username and password

Need code for android

Answer (score 5):

There is no solution to this, Google is telling the people to use the code as the password.  What you can do is have only one screen for signup and login. When `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns null that means that you have to signup/login the user the same way, both options need a code/password that only the phone number owner can have. If you really want phone and password login, you can do something like [this](https://medium.com/@shivampesitbng/firebase-phone-password-auth-in-vue-b94f15b8fb3d)

Answer (score 3):

login firebase thought firebase database on [phone-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

```
// The test phone number and code should be whitelisted in the console.
String phoneNumber = "some_number";
String smsCode = "some_codes";

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuthSettings firebaseAuthSettings = firebaseAuth.getFirebaseAuthSettings();

// Configure faking the auto-retrieval with the whitelisted numbers.
firebaseAuthSettings.setAutoRetrievedSmsCodeForPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, smsCode);

PhoneAuthProvider phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();
phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber,
  60L,
  TimeUnit.SECONDS,
  this, /* activity */
  new OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
      // Instant verification is applied and a credential is directly returned.
    }

    ... /* other callbacks */
  }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you need the user to have a password. At the time of sign up, let the user create a password or use the received code as password and save it in a node in firebase. During the new log in, ask the user for phone and password and if they match, log in the user. Your data will look something like:

```
{
"login":{
        "+1254655826":"123235"
        "+4545492145":"password"
        "+2154644833":"passwordHASH"
    }
    //you can also hash the password
}
```

All you do now is listen to reference login/phone and if password matches the password the user enters or the code sent during sign up, you log in the user.

For phone authentication, refer to this [doc on firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

So the process will be

```
reference.child("login/" + phone).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ->{
    if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
        //user exists
        if(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().matches(password)) //login successful

    }else  PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()
        .verifyPhoneNumber(phone,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS,this,mCallbacks);
})
```

Comment: Thats the thing how to login the user like there are methods in email signUp to signIn user but are not in phone auth.